# Getting error PDO/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm getting the following error

[image]

Link to DBconfig.php ->

Link to code ->

[image]

Can you guys please help me ;)

thank you!

My code ->

```
<?php
    include '../header.php';
    include '../dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_POST['registreer'])){

        $naam = $_POST['naam'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];

        $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO klant(naam, adres, postcode, email, password) 
        values(:name, :adres, :postcode, :woonplaats, :email, :pass) ");

        $insert->bindParam(':naam',$naam);
        $insert->bindParam(':adres',$adres);
        $insert->bindParam(':postcode',$postcode);
        $insert->bindParam(':woonplaats',$woonplaats);
        $insert->bindParam(':email',$email);
        $insert->bindParam(':wachtwoord',$wachtwoord);  

        $insert->execute();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Add your code and the error message to the question.

Comment: This is the link to the code -> https://gyazo.com/cb0f64c9243057df1970075838967a49

Comment: The code needs to be here. You have at least 2 typos I can see from the screenshot.

Comment: sorry im new in stackoverflow i edit the code in the post

Comment: Okay, look at `:name` and `:pass` in your query, then look at your bindings. The `$wachtwoord` also should be hashed but the reason for the error is the mismatched names.

Answer (score 0):

```
values(:name, :adres, :postcode, :woonplaats, :email, :pass) ");
```

You have parameters `:name` and `:pass` but in your bindings you have spelled them in Dutch:

```
$insert->bindParam(':naam',$naam);
$insert->bindParam(':wachtwoord',$wachtwoord);
```

PDO doesn't know how to translate parameter names between English and Dutch. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending to many parameters.

```
$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO klant(naam, adres, postcode, email, password) values(:name, :adres, :postcode, :woonplaats, :email, :pass) ");
```

You have the insert into " naam, adres, postcode, email and password" (that's 5)
And you are trying to insert 6 values.
 "Name, adres, postcode, woonplaats, email and pass.

Sorry for the poor formating, I am on mobile.